# Getting tags value from xml file and saving results in csv file using batch script

Tags: xml, csv, batch-file

I have xml file and need to extract the required tags values and output the result in csv file with tag name has header and below it's value.

so far what I have tried gets the xml tag and values but all the results gets displayed in 1 column instead like table format.

xml file content(partial file content) :

```
<RSP>
<HSI>
<SN>CZ9V      </SN>
<SP>Pro Gen8</SP>
<UUID>C9V</UUID>
</HSI>
<STP>3</STP>
<cUUID>343-11</cUUID>
<NICS>
<NIC>
<PORT>1</PORT>
<MACADDR>01:51:f2</MACADDR>
</NIC>
<NIC>
<PORT>1</PORT>
<MACADDR>00:17</MACADDR>
</NIC>
<NIC>
<PORT>2</PORT>
<MACADDR>77:28:02</MACADDR>
</NIC>
<NIC>
<PORT>3</PORT>
<MACADDR>00:04</MACADDR>
</NIC>
<NIC>
<PORT>4</PORT>
<MACADDR>00:06</MACADDR>
</NIC>
</NICS>
</RSP>
```

output am getting from output.csv file :

```
SN,SP,UUID,MACADDR,cUUID
CZ9V
Pro Gen8
C9V
```

01:51:f2
   343-11

What I was looking to get is :

```
SN,SP,UUID,MACADDR,cUUID
CZ9V,Pro Gen8,C9V,01:51:f2,343-11
```

when we open the output.csv in spreadsheet all the above result should be easy to filter if needed using filter option.

Code so far am to get :

```
echo SN,SP,UUID,MACADDR,cUUID> %outFile%
set req_tags=SN SP UUID MACADDR cUUID
for %%a in (%inFile%) do (
for %%c in (%req_tags%) do (
set "found="
set search_tag=%%c
for /f "tokens=2 delims=><  " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i !search_tag! ' ) do set found=%%b
 if defined found >> "%outFile%" echo !found! 
)
)
```

need to get the tag vlaue under respective tag name in output.csv file.

Comment: Your proposed output is a fixed width text file, which is totally different from a CSV.

Comment: ok got it. I shouldn't have formatted the expected output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the requirements have changed a bit, I elected to post a new answer instead of editing the original one. Not sure if that's the way to do things, but hey, I try my best... :)

Here's a version that doesn't care about the XML hierarchy, it just extracts token values from a list of specified elements. However, note that as I explained earlier, the case where multiple children may belong to a common parent element (even though the XML hierarchy doesn't reflect it) is **not** handled here. But the output is on a single line, as request by the OP:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set req_tags=SN SP UUID MACADDR cUUID
set inFile="C:\tests\xmltocsv.txt"
set outFile="C:\tests\output.csv"
if exist %outFile% del %outFile%

rem set the header line
set hLine=
for %%a in (%req_tags%) do (
  set hLine=!hLine!,%%a
)
call :outputlinetocsv "%hLine%"

rem add values to file
set csvLine=
for %%a in (%req_tags%) do (
  set sTag=%%a
  for /F "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%f in ('findstr /I /L "^</!sTag!" %inFile%') do (
    set line=%%f
    set "line=!line:*>=!"
    set csvLine=!csvLine!,!line!
  )
)
call :outputlinetocsv "%csvLine%"
goto :eof

:outputlinetocsv
REM remove starting comma
set myLine=%~1
set "myLine=!myLine:*,=!"
echo !myLine! >> %outFile%
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks Filipus. your second code works as expected. only issue what  I have seen is if the reg_tag occurs more than once in the input xml file then your code gets both values. like in mycase, UUID appears twice in input file.

Comment: Yes, that's what I explained in my post: multiple children cannot be handled like this. You could write exceptions to handle those cases, but if you want to make it absolutely generic, you'd have to use an actual XML parser from a Scripting language, as I suggested in one of my previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at it. You were on the right track. The following code looks like it's working for the sample data you posted and it will keep working for any additional item you add inside the HSI element.

The only thing you need to modify is the CSV header line, but you could elect to pass that as a parameter to the batch file or to hardcode the values inside the batch file itself, as they are now:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inFile="C:\tests\xmltocsv.txt"
set outFile="C:\tests\output.csv"
if exist %outFile% del %outFile%
set csvline=
echo SN SP UUID > %outFile%
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L /V "^<HSI" %inFile%') do (
  if "%%a" EQU "</HSI>" (
    echo !csvline! & set csvline=
  ) ELSE (
   set line=%%a & set "line=!line:*>=!" & for /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") do (IF "%%b" NEQ " " (IF "!csvline!" NEQ "" (set csvline=!csvline! %%b) ELSE (set csvline=%%b)))
  )
)) >> %outFile%
```

Comment: Thanks Filipus but when I run your code, I didn't get any value in the output.csv file. moreover, input file will have tags and the required tags/values will under different parent tag (not just tags which is there inside  <HSI>) So, I was thinking to set a variable for ex : requried_tags="SN SP UUID .. .. ... etc" and in the code it should fetch these tag values and result gets into output.csv with very first row having tag name and below it's corresponding value. Sorry I should have given proper input.xml file content not just a part. (which I have updated it now)

Comment: ok, I made some changes in the code so defined requried_tag can be searched and send the value to output.csv. it's working but all the tag values getting under first column one after the another. not sure what I need to do now. bit struck any help/suggestion most welcome. I have updated the initial code/output what am getting now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you can tell which tags belongs to which item if they are not stored under the same parent. Your example shows that you are matching items under the /NICS/NIC element with an item under the HSI element, but presumably you could have several NIC elements, so how would you match them with the corresponding HSI element? Are there multiple instances of HSI elements in your input file? Are they grouped under a HSIS parent?

Comment: All the tags are placed under Parent tag called <RSP>

Comment: Still, could you have several NIC elements corresponding to a single HSI element or is there always a one-to-one match (in which case, one would assume there is also a HSIS parent element)?

Comment: Yes Filipus, there will several NIC tag under HSI parent. I have updated the input xml file to give clear picture. sorry for not giving full input file.

Comment: If you have several NIC tags associated with a single corresponding HSI element, are you planning on repeating the HSI-specific values on each line? For instance, someting like
'SN,SP,UUID,MACADDR,cUUID'
'CZ9V,Pro Gen8,C9V,01:51:f2,343-11'
'CZ9V,Pro Gen8,C9V,08:32:d1,646-37'

Comment: Given that your requirements are becoming increasingly complex, it seems to me you may want to use a JS/VB script that uses XML parsing rather than a batch file

Comment: hmm ok. Thanks Filipus. how about getting the required output format.. currently output result get stored one after another instead of next to eachother format with "," (comma) in between.

Comment: I posted a second answer, which takes a different approach, given the different source file.